# How do I generate a qqplot from raster data?

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a `qqplot` relating to a DEM that I produced by differencing two DEMs using R. I have generated several `qqplot`s in the past, but this is my first attempt to generate one from a raster.

When I attempt to generate the `qqplot` I am given a warning and error, of which I am unsure its meaning (see below).

How do produce a `qqplot` plot for my raster in R?

**Input:**

```
setwd("N:/x/y/data") 
DEM1 <-raster("DEM1") ; DEM2<-raster("DEM2")
DEM_Diff= DEM2 - DEM1
qqplot(DEM_Diff, main="Q-Q Plot:DEM_Diff")
```

**Output:**

```
Warning message:
In any(<S4 object of class "RasterLayer">, na.rm = FALSE) :
  Nothing to summarize if you provide a single RasterLayer; see cellStats
Error in x[order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)] : 
error in evaluating the argument 'i' in selecting a method for function '[':Error in !is.na(na.last) && any(nas) : invalid 'y' type in 'x && y'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`qqplot` requires 2 data sets as input (it plots one distribution against another).  For a single data set, you can use `qqnorm` to plot against a normal distribution.  You can pass the raster data to qqnorm either by specifying the slots in which the data are stored, or by extracting the values first:

```
library(raster)
r=raster(volcano)
qqnorm(values(r))
# qqnorm(r@data@values) also works
# qqnorm(as.matrix(r)) also works
```

[image]

In case what you are actually attempting to do is to plot the distribution of one raster against another (this was not clear from the question) you can do `qqplot(values(r1), values(r2))`